# ubuntu on tonbux 10 inch tablet

Tags: 12.04

I am a big fun of ubuntu.  I recently bought a tonbux tablet 10 inch with android.  I have tried to install ubuntu on it but I don't seem to be able to unlock the device, has anyone tried this before on a tonbux tablet?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, verify that your tablet is supported by Ubuntu touch, [check this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices).
Then, [check this tutorial](http://developer.ubuntu.com/start/ubuntu-for-devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/) to unlock and install Ubuntu on your device

Comment: Thanks Mohamed.  I managed to root the tablet with kingroot (although it was freezing the tablet,) after many re-runs it eventually rooted it.  Next problem was to boot the tonbux tablet in bootloader.  After many tries I found somewhere information that the A10 allwinner won't allow bootloader.  Eventually I gave up and ended up buying a nexus 7 2013 wifi, now I have installed ubuntu touch on my nexus and quite happy :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is not, this is a cheap tablet I bought from amazon at an affordable price of 70GBP, quite surprise it is not even yet a work-in-progress.  Anyway, if anyone has tried this before please let us know.